# Which contacts in Civi are wordPress user as well?

Tags: wordpress, contacts, user

I have 500 contacts on my CiviCRM groups and also I have 250 users for my WordPress, I am wondering to know is any way to find which one of my civiContacts are in WordPress?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to search via Adv Search and find a button called CMS User.

Comment: This should answer your question @raha.  On a somewhat related note, you can also use the plugin CiviCRM Wordpress Member Sync to have accounts created for all your contacts that don't have Wordpress accounts.  If you have Buddy Press you can use CiviCRM WordPress Profile Sync.